# Does garrisoning Longbowmen etc cause them to fire to defend a town centre, keep etc?

Tags: age-of-empires-iv

I thought I read somewhere that if you garrison longbowmen or other ranged units in a town centre that they'll fire out to defend the town centre / keep etc?

But I can't confirm this anywhere, is it true?